# how to control remote desktop keyboard and mouse events using python even if i disconnect remote desktop

Tags: python, ctypes, remote-desktop

i want to control keyboard and mouse using python on remote desktop even if the connection is broken rdp wont stop hitting events.I am using windows ec2 on amazon

right now i am using

```
def PressKey(hexKeyCode):

extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
ii_ = Input_I()
ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( hexKeyCode, 0x48, 0, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra) )
x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))
```

def ReleaseKey(hexKeyCode):

```
extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
ii_ = Input_I()
ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( hexKeyCode, 0x48, 0x0002, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra) )
x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))
```

this is a library of ctypes in python which work on hex codes of keyboard.It does work on my machine and remote desktop but when i disconnect it stops working.

Please help me

Comment: err, if there is no link, how can you can you transmit an order remotely ?

Comment: my python script is running on remote desktop

Comment: Do you mean that you are remotely starting a script which is supposed to run on its own, and then you close the connection? The problem is when you close the connection, the processes that are part of that connection also close, so you should either not close the connection, or have the script first spawn a new process which is not tied to the parent connection.

Comment: the problem is when i disconnect the rdp script does not stops but it does not any thing but when i connect to rdp again it start working again.

Comment: can you just help me in this `or have the script first spawn a new process which is not tied to the parent connection`??

Comment: @InbarRose please help

Comment: Ask a new question which is about networking, your problem is not about ctypes or keyboard presses at all.